# Unable to execute selenium code through selenium grid hosted in azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-devops, selenium-grid

I have installed docker on my azure virtual machine (operating system:Linux (ubuntu 20.04)) to perform parallel testing. I am trying to run selenium code through selenium grid hosted in azure virtual machine using docker container.

**Public IP of VM: 30.245.169.151**

I am using below command to run my containers.

```
docker run -d -p 4545:4444 --name selenium-hub selenium/hub
```

and

```
docker run -d -P --link  selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome-debug
```

I am trying to access grid from my local windows machine using below url : http://30.245.169.151:4545 but not able to access it. I am not sure if I am missing something to access grid from the azure virtual machine docker container.

Also I am unable to execute below code through selenium grid.

Code :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

    RemoteWebDriver driver = null;

    DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    dc.setBrowserName("chrome");

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://30.245.169.151:4545/wd/hub"), dc);

    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());


    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //Locating the elements using name locator for the text box
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("YouTube");

   //name locator for google search button
    WebElement searchIcon = driver.findElement(By.name("btnK"));
    searchIcon.click();
}
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!